# How to implement/design a website?

Tags: web-services, web

website designing, databases and etc are not my field. However, I have an idea and would like to implement it. In order to do so, I need to design a website which lets users log in and then they can post content to the webiste. Probably, they would have to use their credit cards for purchases too.

The way I see it is that I would have to have database to store profile info, contents posted by users. Also, some sort of mechanism to perform transactions. Also, I need a server which handles the client requests (probably in Java or etc).

I am familiar with some of the web languages but haven't done any project in that field. So my question is what are the languages I need to know? What is the easiest one? Where do I start? In general if you had to do the facebook how do you start?

Comment: This is an absolutely massive topic, there are entire books on the subject that barely scratch the surface. I suggest you do some Googling first

Comment: Your question isn't really [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow. I might suggest posting in https://www.reddit.com/r/askcomputerscience

Comment: I have done some googling. As a matter of fact I have taken databases, distributed system at school. But never really went deep into it. Specially in terms of websites.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister maybe I can find better answers there thanks. But Stackoverflow accepts a question if it [generally covers software tools commonly used by programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). So I tought it's ok.

Comment: @EhsanAb I understand the confusion, it's not entirely clear in the reference. Personally I would say this question falls under #4 about asking to find off-site resources. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), particularly "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." Best of luck in finding a good online resource (or book!) that will help you learn backend web development in order to accomplish what you're trying to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that is a very general question... However:
You basically only need to know html/javascript(css) and a serverside language.
Normally you wouldn't implement a full server that handles the client request, but use an existing one and just write the code that generates the answer, the server side code(could be PHP, C#, VB, Also JS(using node.js)), which is running on a webserver (such as apache(php), IIS(.net languages(c#, vb..)).
You should pick a server-side language that fits you and then read some tutorials on how to create a simple webpage, how sessions work(for log-in) and how you can integrate a db. Concerning the payment issue: there are lots of payment apis out there you could easily integrate in your page (however most of them will charge you transaction fees or cost monthly).
so:

1. Pick a [server-side language](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Scripting) (i prefer c# (MVC))
2. Install development environment(server, etc)
3. Read tutorials and practise
4. Build your web-app step-by-step